# Conditionally color portion of the text of the UITextField

Tags: iphone, graphics, uitextfield, uicolor

I've a UITextField, I need to color some specific word in a `gray`

Is there a direct solution?

If not, I think If I got the Source code for `setTextColor` method, try to conditinoally change its implementation (may be through a `Category` or even `subclassing`).

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible as is. To implement that kind of feature you have to use CoreText.

For more info read this great tutorial: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/befriending-core-text/